# Get first day and last day dates of month of selected date in Marklogic

Tags: date, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to get first day and last day dates of any selected date using MarkLogic.
Example:

```
let $date := xs:date("2018-08-24")      
let $firstDay := "*Should be 1st day of month - of $date*"  
let $lastDay := "*Should be last day of month - of $date*"  
return ("$firstDay:",$firstDay,"$lastDay:",$lastDay)
```

**Expected Output dates:**

- `$firstDay: 2018-08-01`
- `$lastDay: 2018-08-31`

I can able to get this dates by using *functx:first-day-of-month($date)* and
*functx:last-day-of-month($date)* but I wanted to know is there any API or alternative option provided by **MarkLogic**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute this directly using standard XQuery [duration arithmetic](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#durations):

```
let $date := xs:date("2018-08-24")

let $one-day := xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
let $one-month := xs:yearMonthDuration('P1M')
(: subtract days to get to the 1st of the month :)
let $firstDay := $date - (fn:day-from-date($date) - 1) * $one-day
(: get the 1st of the next month and then subtract one day :)
let $lastDay  := $firstDay + $one-month - $one-day

return ("$firstDay:",$firstDay,"$lastDay:",$lastDay)
```

Comment: This is useful. don't we have any ready API provided byMarkLogic?

Comment: functx is available as a library module in MarkLogic: `import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xqy";`

Comment: Specifically, http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_first-day-of-month.html and http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_last-day-of-month.html

Comment: Yes,we can use functx functions but I was checking instead of importing external functions (functx) and using in ML, don't we have something in MarkLogic itself. Earlier I was using functx but now I have an internal arithmatic duration computed function  as @Leo Wörteler suggested in above answer. Thanks.

Comment: I also see a simple way of calculating 1st date of any selected date using substring function.  
xs:date(fn:concat(fn:substring(xs:string($date),1,8), "01"))